# How to check response of Pac script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, pac

I need to get the response of the pacScript in my chrome extension.A [pacScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_(PAC)_file#Return_value_format) will return `DIRECT` string in case we don't need to proxy and i want to detect that.

```
var config = {
        mode: "pac_script",
        pacScript: {
          url: "https://www.example.com/proxy.pac"
        }
      };

chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: 'regular'},function() {
    //how can i get the pac response string here 
});
```

Edit :
I tried using `JQuery.getScript` to load the `FindProxyForURL` from remote pac file but now the pac specific function like `isPlainHostName` are now undefined.

I could get the implementations from [mozilla](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/ProxyAutoConfig.cpp) but there must be a better way since those are browser functions that should have already been available.

Comment: Since it's a normal javacript, you can run it, see [Using eval in Chrome Extensions. Safely](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval).

Comment: @wOxxOm Can you show an example and do you think that this solution will work for other browsers like firefox

Comment: I don't have any examples. The examples are in the link I gave, and you can find more using google search, hopefully. As for Firefox, you can use an iframe with the correctly specified [sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) attributes in any modern browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is simply not possible. This is because a pac file is evaluated for each url you request. So, the 'pac response string' is not a constant that can be returned upon setting the proxy settings.

If you're trying to debug your pac file, you can `alert('settings')` inside the `FindProxyForURL` just before returning the settings. The alert creates a log entry which can be accessed via `chrome://net-internals/#events` functionality.

If you only want to test if the user is using direct connection or proxy, you can compare the external ip address before and after setting proxy settings. Checkout [ipify.org](https://ipify.org) or you can even use a script on your own web server.

Here's some sample code for this:

```
let originalIp = "";

async function getCurrentIp() {
    var res = await fetch('http://api.ipify.org/');
    return await res.text();
}

// Get ip before setting proxy
getCurrentIp().then(ip => {
    originalIp = ip;
});

var config = {
    mode: "pac_script",
    pacScript: {
        url: "https://www.example.com/proxy.pac"
    }
};

chrome.proxy.settings.set({
    value: config,
    scope: 'regular'
}, function() {
    // Get ip after setting proxy and compare it with original ip
    getCurrentIp().then(ip => {
        if (ip == originalIp)
            console.log('DIRECT');
        else
            console.log('PROXY: ' + ip)
    })
});
```